# Web or desktop app for tracking tasks I am working on to the minute

Tags: windows, time-management

Can you recommend me a tool, commercial or free, for tracking tasks I am working on? I would prefer a desktop app but an web app is fine as well. I do not want to use an app on the phone.

I am working on multiple overlapping things and I want to keep track of all of them. The app should support the following workflow:

- create a task and start it immediately. The app should record the time when it started and when I end it.
- I want to be able to specify estimates for a task and then compare them to the actual time it took to execute a task.
- while other tasks are opened in the background, I might start another one. I should be able to pause the existing running tasks or leave them running
- I should be able to add sub-tasks to a task.

Thanks!